# XML to GrapML using stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to convert an `XML` file to a `GraphMl` format using a xsl stylesheet (see below), the `from` and `to` attributes in the link are to be used as the `source` and `target` attributes in the `GraphMl` file. My code runs but the output file is empty, how can I fix the stylesheet?

Sample XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE network SYSTEM "http://www.matsim.org/files/dtd/network_v2.dtd">
<network>

    <!-- ====================================================================== -->

        <nodes>
            <node id="MyCiTi_1" x="-53196.450154726146" y="-3755010.0058102254" >
            </node>
            <node id="MyCiTi_10" x="-54879.37761845079" y="-3753903.660850382" >
            </node>
            <node id="MyCiTi_100" x="-46659.23389528884" y="-3749500.821686937" >
            </node>
        </nodes>

    <!-- ====================================================================== -->

        <links capperiod="01:00:00" effectivecellsize="7.5" effectivelanewidth="3.75">
            <link id="MyCiTi_0" from="MyCiTi_180" to="MyCiTi_180" length="50.0" freespeed="8.333333333333334" capacity="500.0" >
            </link>
            <link id="MyCiTi_1" from="MyCiTi_180" to="MyCiTi_58" length="608.4643035761809" freespeed="8.333333333333334" capacity="500.0"  >
            </link>
            <link id="MyCiTi_10" from="MyCiTi_176" to="MyCiTi_192" length="868.3169964115151" freespeed="8.333333333333334" capacity="500.0" >
            </link>
        </links>

</network>
```

xsl sheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd">
        <key id="nodes" for="node" attr.name="id" attr.type="string"/>
        <key id="edges" for="edge" attr.name="id" attr.type="string"/>
        <graph id="g" edgedefault="undirected">
                <xsl:for-each select="node">
                    <node>
                        <data key="node">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@x"/>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@y"/>
                        </data>
                    </node>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:for-each select="link">
                    <edge source="@from" target="@to">
                        <data key="link">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@length"/>
                        </data>
                    </edge>
                </xsl:for-each>
        </graph>
    </graphml>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The paths do not work properly. If you want to do this with `for-each`, you need to start at `network`.
2. To transfer information directly into other attributes you just need to put these in `{}`.
3. I think you should insert one space character between your coordinates.
4. The nodes should also have IDs, right?

Try this:

```
<graph id="g" edgedefault="undirected">
<xsl:for-each select="network/nodes/node">
    <node id="{@id}">
        <data key="node">
            <xsl:value-of select="@x"/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@y"/>
        </data>
    </node>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:for-each select="network/links/link">
        <edge source="{@from}" target="{@to}">
            <data key="link">
               <xsl:value-of select="@length"/>
            </data>
        </edge>
    </xsl:for-each>
</graph>
```